# Use only the main road when drag

Tags: here-api, here-fleet-telematics

Create a route from 42.108311,-8.618618999999999 to 52.2947946,11.6822273. I try to drag the route from Villadolid to road N-610, screen https://snipboard.io/CR6wVn.jpg , pre-drawn correctly. After releasing the mouse button,the route is different, there is a turn easter of Cuenca de Campos, screen https://snipboard.io/VWJ1vL.jpg. How can only the main roads when used drag?

Drag request like this

https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json?xnlp=jsonAttributes%3D41&app_id=***&app_code=***&apikey=***&mode=truck%3Bfastest%3Btraffic%3Adisabled&language=en-GB&representation=overview&metricSystem=metric&routeattributes=wp%2Csc%2Csm%2Csh%2Cbb%2Clg%2Cno%2Cshape&legattributes=wp%2Cmn%2Cli%2Cle%2Ctt&maneuverattributes=po%2Csh%2Ctt%2Cle%2Cti%2Cli%2Cpt%2Cpl%2Crn%2Cnr%2Cdi&linkattributes=sh%2Cle%2Csl%2Cds%2Ctr&instructionformat=html&trailersCount=0&alternatives=0&currency=EUR&trailerType=2&vehicleNumberAxles=2&trailerNumberAxles=3&hybrid=0&emissionType=5&height=4m&trailerHeight=400&vehicleWeight=8000&limitedWeight=40t&width=225&length=16.5m&disabledEquipped=0&minimalPollution=0&hov=0&passengersCount=1&commercial=1&heightAbove1stAxle=300&fuelType=Diesel&detail=1&rollup=none%2Ccountry%3Btollsys&requestId=1629721987441&excludeCountries=CHE&truckRestrictionPenalty=soft&waypoint0=geo!42.1083257%2C-8.6184468&waypoint1=geo!42.037725092800514%2C-5.039375866201198&waypoint2=geo!52.2952544%2C11.6801417&jsoncallback=H.service.jsonp.handleResponse(12)

Comment: Hi,  to better understand your question, could you share additional information? 
(1) the original routing request; 
(2) the request while dragging; 
(3) the request while releasing the mouse

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport The main question is: how to ignore exits when planning a route? Like here https://snipboard.io/VWJ1vL.jpg